# How to move and recreate a folder at the same time?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rename

I have a folder called `statistics` in an Ubuntu server in which data files are regularly stored. How can I rename `statistics` folder to `backup-xx` while re-creating `statistics` folder to be available for storing new files?

The files in `statistics` folder is created by PHP `file_put_contents`.

I prefer renaming the folder, as there are many files in the `statistics` folder.

Comment: At first I thought you meant with _"at the same time"_ that the operation should be _"atomic"_ (as far as it is possible).

Comment: @phk Yes, it is exactly what I meant.

Comment: The correct terminology would be "directory" and not "folder" by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mv statistics backup-xx && mkdir statistics
```

This would rename the existing `statistics` directory to `backup-xx`, and if that succeeds it would carry on to create a new `statistics` directory.

For a more atomic operation, consider creating a directory `statistics-001` (or similar, maybe by replacing `001` with today's date in a suitable format), and a symbolic link to it called `statistics`:

```
mkdir statistics-001
ln -s statistics-001 statistics
```

When you want to "rotate" this so that new data goes into a clean directory, create the directory first, then recreate the `statistics` link to it:

```
mkdir statistics-002
ln -sf statistics-002 statistics

mv statistics-001 backup-001
```

This way, any program writing to the `statistics` directory (i.e. the directory that this symbolic link points to) will never<sup>1</sup> fail to find it.

If you need special permissions or ownership set on the directory that `statistics` points to, set these before (re-)creating the link.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Or rather, this way, the time that a program would be *without* a valid target directory is minimized as much as practically possible using standard Unix tools.</sub>

Comment: You may also want a `chown --reference=backup-xx statistics ; chmod --reference=backup-xx statistics` to set ownerships and permissions.  Ideall you would do this before renaming, so a `mkdir new ; chown ; chmod ; mv stats backup ; mv new stats` type process.

Comment: @StephenHarris Yes, on systems that have those flags.

Comment: This isn't atomic, though. It's *close* to atomic, but not quite.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Fixed it.

Comment: `ln -sf` is not atomic. It's specified to unlink the old symlink then make a new one, which is necessarily non-atomic. Instead you must make an additional temporary symlink and use the `rename` function (via the `mv` command, for instance) to atomically replace the old one. See my approach to it here: https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/tools/install.sh?id=7cbb6f70c8fe711644ec0dbede1973cc6641a283

Comment: Also note that my approach has some limitations when there could be directories involved; these can be mitigated via additional tricks using temporary directories.

Answer (score 13):

There's no way to *atomically* replace a directory by another directory. You can move the old directory then create a new directory:

```
mv statistics backup-xx
mkdir statistics
```

But this leaves a small window of time during which `statistics` doesn't exist. This is a problem if some process may drop files in the directory at any time.

To effectively atomically replace a directory, you need to use symbolic links. Create a directory whose name includes the time period from the start:

```
mkdir "statistics-$(date +%Y%m%d)"
```

(or however you want to choose the directory naming convention). Create a symbolic link with a fixed name to the current location:

```
ln -s … statistics
```

To replace the directory, first create a new directory and a new symbolic link, and then move it to overwrite the old symbolic link. Note that neither a plain `mv` on the symbolic link nor a plain `ln -s` will do this: they would create an entry inside the target directory. GNU coreutils's `ln -snf` isn't suitable either because it removes the existing symlink before creating a new one, which leaves a small time window during which the path doesn't exist. You can use GNU coreutils's `mv -T` on the new symbolic link.

```
new_dir="statistics-$(date +%Y%m%d)"
mkdir "$new_dir"
ln -s statistics.new
mv -Tf statistics.new statistics
```

Comment: `busybox`' `ln -sf` also isn't atomic, I don't know of any implementation that is.

Comment: Beside phk's comment symlinks are also not 100% safe because a running process may still have an open directory file descriptor (symlink target) and it could create more new files in the renamed directory (think about `openat()` or CWD). I would only move the *content* of the directory to a new one. That's is still unsafe regarding open files, but a bit better. In doubt use `logrotate` which should respect such issues best possible.

Comment: @phk The `symlink` system call won't overwrite an existing file, so it's impossible to directly switch a symbolic link atomically, unfortunately. The `rename` system call will overwrite an existing file, but annoyingly there's no portable way to do it in the shell; it's possible with GNU coreutils thanks to the `-T` option.

Answer (score 3):

Don't rename the directory at all. You said that you prefer renaming the directory because it has a lot of files. The only reason I can think of that you would want this is because copying the files would take too long. However, *moving* (i.e. renaming) the files is instantaneous as long as they are moved to a location on the same file system. I assume this is what you ant to do since if you're changing file systems, `mv` will take as much time as `cp` no matter whether it is moving a directory or its contents.

So, just do:

```
mkdir backup-xx && mv statistics/* backup-xx
```

If you need to also get hidden files, you can do:

```
mkdir backup-xx && mv statistics/* statistics/.* backup-xx
```

Or, if using `bash`:

```
shopt -s dotglob; mkdir backup-xx && mv statistics/* statistics/.* backup-xx
```

This way, the directory is always there but you still move its contents in a simple and fast operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the contents of the statistics folder to a newly created directory rather than moving folder itself. If you move entire folder then you would have to run another command to change the directory permissions.

```
mkdir -p <path>/backup-xxx
mv statistics/* <path>/backup-xxx/.
```